# Upload multiple Images from Next JS to Strapi API

Tags: reactjs, next.js, strapi

I'm currently working on a website using Strapi as a CMS and Next.js (React) in Frontend.
How can I add multiple images from NextJS to Strapi Media library? I Try to upload the image from the NextJS frontend, the image will be uploaded to my Strapi Media library . I tried these line of code but steel have an empty formData .

```
const uploadData = new FormData();
const handleFileChange = (e) => {
files = e.target.files
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
             const file = files[i];
             uploadData.append('images[]', file, file.name);
           }
console.log(uploadData)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in the documentation here https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/upload.html#examples:

Frontend

```
<form>
  <!-- Can be multiple files -->
  <input type="file" name="files" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  const form = document.querySelector('form');

  form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    await fetch('/api/upload', {
      method: 'post',
      body: new FormData(e.target)
    });
  });
</script>
```

Backend

```
import { FormData } from 'formdata-node';
import fetch, { blobFrom } from 'node-fetch';

const file = await blobFrom('./1.png', 'image/png');
const form = new FormData();

form.append('files', file, "1.png");

const response = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/upload', {
  method: 'post',
  body: form,
});
```

Comment: The upload of one image is done well ! but I have a problem on the upload of multiple images ! I dont know how send the images data to 'http://localhost:1337/upload' witch are relatated to a specific entry  . I googled for hours but no proposition could help me .

Comment: @Ahmed did you try multiple `form.append('files', file, "1.png");` calls (one for each file)?